# Probability Normal Approximation

Tags: probability, probability-theory, approximation

I am trying to understand this example for normal approximations:

In a particular faculty 60% of students are men and 40% are women. In a random sample of 50 students what is the probability that more than half are women?

Let the random variable $X$ be the number of women in the sample.

Assume $X$ has the binomial distribution with $n = 50$ and $p = 0.4$.

Then $E(X)=np=50\times 0.4=20$

$\operatorname{var}(X) = npq = 50 \times 0.4 \times 0.6 = 12$

so approximately $X \sim N(20,12)$.

We need to find $P(X > 25)$. Note - not $P(X >= 25)$.

so
$$
P(X > 25) = P(Z > 1.44)\\
= 1 - P(Z < 1.44)\\
= 1 - 0.9251\\
= 0.075
$$

I don't understand the line near the bottom beginning at $1-P(Z > 1.44)$. Where do you get the value for $P(Z > 1.44)$?

Comment: Traditionally, in the days of A&S, you would look up a table of standard normal values. Now your pocket calculator can handle even the original normal distribution, no questions asked.

Comment: How can i do Z < 1.44?

Comment: Check out this link: http://www.statisticshowto.com/what-is-the-continuity-correction-factor/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using a continuity correction and finding $$p(X>25.5)$$

So if you are using a table of $z$ values, you will be finding $$1-\Phi(1.59)$$

Or if you have a new calculator with the Normal CD function, you can get a more accurate answer $0.05617559886$